# GenericArguments[0], 'AuthRepository', on '.UserApplication`1[TRepository]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRepository'

Tags: c#, generics

What I want to achieve is to successfully pass IAuthRepository to the UserApplication.cs

I really don't know where I am going wrong?

The reason why I want to pass the IAuthRepository to the UserApplication class is because I version that I'd have different repository e.g ISalesRepository that persist the data to a different database so that is why I want to have different repositories.

I have an interface that I am coding against

```
     public interface IUserApplication <TRepository> where TRepository : IRepository
        {
            User Authenticate(string username, string password);            
        }
```

And I class called UserApplication that implements IUserApplication

```
    public class UserApplication<TRepository> where TRepository: IRepository, IUserApplication<TRepository>
        {
            private readonly IUserService<TRepository> _user;
    
            public UserApplication(IUserService<TRepository> user)
            {
                _user = user;
            }}
```

Startup.cs, and of course I am using dependency injection

```
           
            `services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserApplication<>), typeof(UserApplication<>));``

On a controller level
```

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserApplication<IAuthRepository> _userApplication;    
        private IAuthRepository _authRepository;

        public UserController(IUserApplication<IAuthRepository> userApplication)
        {
            _userApplication = userApplication;
        }}
```

Comment: And the definition for `IAuthRepository` is?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface 

looks like this
public class AuthRepository : Repository, IAuthRepository
    {
    }



And on the Repository class, there just add and delete methods.


and I am also adding it to the IoC in the startup

services.AddSingleton<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>()

Comment: That doesn't implement `IUserApplication<>`

Comment: Hi @Charlieface thank you for that. could you kindly show me an example how to go about it.